# Safari - refresh page instead using cached page - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, caching, safari

Does anyone know a way, via JavaScript, that I can either clear Safari's bfcache, or force it to reload rather that used a cached version of a page?

I have a web application that is running tests, and there is JavaScript which monitors a countdown (a timeout):

```
timeoutId = window.setInterval(function () {
    timeoutRemaining--;
    if (timeoutRemaining <= 0) {
        location.href = myTimeoutLocation;
    }
}, timeoutInterval);
```

This all works fine until I get to myTimeoutLocation. The behavior is that, if a user clicks the back button, the test should continue. However, when navigating back, I find that IE and Chrome reload the page, but Firefox and Safari are showing the cached page. I need to make sure that a cached page is NEVER shown. I can fix this problem in Firefox by adding:

```
window.onunload = function () { };
```

to my script, but that hasn't worked in Safari since Safari 5.x (as far as I can tell). I found another solution:

```
window.addEventListener("pageshow", function(evt){
    if(evt.persisted){
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.location.reload();
        },10);
    }
}, false);
```

This worked to an extent... The problem I have now is that even with the above code, I am receiving a dialog box: ... which I'm apparently not allowed to embed. The dialog says that in order to display the page, information must be sent to the server, with the appropriate confirm or deny buttons. I did try setting forceGet to true, but that did not solve the problem with the dialog appearing. I should mention that clicking Resend has the desired effect.

[Non-embedded image of dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyRqZ.png)

And yes, I realize the image is of Firefox, not Safari.

In case it makes any difference (even though this is a JavaScript question), the site is coded in .NET/MVC4 and is hosted in IIS.

Thank you in advance for any help/thoughts/information/pointers in the right direction.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. So you are trying to force the browser to actually reload the previous page when the user clicks on the back button (or other equivalent actions that go back in history)?

Comment: For Safari, I am trying to make sure that it does not load pages from its cache. It needs to reload the page, as IE, Chrome, and (with a little code) Firefox all do.

Comment: One thing that I don't understand is that why do you absolutely need to reload the page upon pressing the back button.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that the WHY is important. However, if it helps me get an answer... When, utilizing the JavaScript at the top of this question, we get to the point that we redirect to the Timout URL, then  timeoutRemaining will have a cached value of zero or less. That means that I will be redirected AGAIN to the Timeout URL after one minute, which is the period of time the system is set to check for timeouts. If the page reloads rather than getting the value from a cache, like all the other browsers are, then timeoutRemaining will be reset to the original timeout value.